# "temporary" variant not showing in Drawer component Material-ui

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to make the drawer component on material-ui a responsive drawer, by making it to be toggled open and close on smaller screens and permanent on desktop

I followed the documentation on mui, which says to add the `temporary` variant to the drawer, however it doesn't show up at all on desktop mode

Below is my drawer component

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

import { makeStyles, Typography, Drawer, Toolbar, Divider, List, ListItem, ListItemText, ListItemIcon, Container, Box } from "@material-ui/core";

import HomeOutlinedIcon from '@material-ui/icons/HomeOutlined';
import AlternateEmailOutlinedIcon from '@material-ui/icons/AlternateEmailOutlined';
import NotificationsNoneOutlinedIcon from '@material-ui/icons/NotificationsNoneOutlined';
import DashboardOutlinedIcon from '@material-ui/icons/DashboardOutlined';
import ArchiveOutlinedIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ArchiveOutlined';


const drawerWidth = 280

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    drawer : {
      width: drawerWidth,
    },
    drawerPaper : {
      width: drawerWidth,
    },
    list : {
      marginLeft: '24px',
      marginRight: '24px'
    },
    listItem : {
      padding: '8px',
      borderRadius: '5px',
    },
    text : {
      color: theme.palette.primary.light,
      fontWeight: '500',
      lineHeight: '2000'
    },
    title : {
      color: theme.palette.primary.light,
      textAlign: 'center',
      display: 'block',
      fontWeight: '500',
      fontSize: '20px',
      marginTop: '10px',
      marginBottom: '10px'
    }
}));

export default function LeftBar(){

  const classes = useStyles();
  const [mobileOpen, setMobileOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const handleDrawerToggle = () => {
    setMobileOpen(!mobileOpen);
  };

  const list = [
    {
      text : 'Home',
      icon : <HomeOutlinedIcon />,
      path : '/'
    },
    {
      text : 'Personal',
      icon : <AlternateEmailOutlinedIcon />,
      path : '/'
    },
    {
      text : 'Notificatons',
      icon : <NotificationsNoneOutlinedIcon />,
      path : '/'
    },
    {
      text : 'Dashboard',
      icon : <DashboardOutlinedIcon />,
      path : '/'
    },
    {
      text : 'Archives',
      icon : <ArchiveOutlinedIcon />,
      path : '/'
    }
  ];

   return (
     <Box>
      <Drawer 
      className={classes.drawer} 
      anchor="left" classes={{
        paper: classes.drawerPaper
      }} 
      open={mobileOpen}
      onClose={handleDrawerToggle}
      ModalProps={{
        keepMounted: true, // Better open performance on mobile.
      }}
      sx={{
        display: { xs: 'block', sm: 'none' },
        flexShrink: 0,
        '& .MuiDrawer-paper': { boxSizing: 'border-box', width: drawerWidth },
      }} 
    >

        <Toolbar />
        <Container>
        <Typography variant="h5" component="h2" className={classes.title} gutterBottom>
        My Account
        </Typography>
        </Container>
        <Divider />

        <List className={classes.list}>
        { list.map((item) => (
        <ListItem key={item.text} className={classes.listItem} button>
          <ListItemIcon className={classes.icon}>
          {item.icon}
          </ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText sx={{color: 'primary'}} primary={item.text} className={classes.text}/>
    
        </ListItem>
        ))}
        </List>

      </Drawer>
      </Box>
   );

};
```

Answer (score 0):

You have only included the drawer for xs - with `display: { xs: 'block', sm: 'none' }` that drawer will not display for any size but xs. You will need another drawer for sm and up. The MUI docs show a second drawer like this:

```
 <Drawer
      variant="permanent"
      sx={{
        display: { xs: 'none', sm: 'block' },
        '& .MuiDrawer-paper': { boxSizing: 'border-box', width: drawerWidth },
      }}
      open
 >
      {you would put your list stuff here}
 </Drawer>
```

You will probably need to move the Toolbar component outside of the Drawer component.